# Entity Framework Core 2 - save empty string as null in database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, interceptor

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2 in my application. I have a lot of nullable string columns in my database.

The problem is that I want to save empty strings as `NULL` in the database.

In old versions of EF, I used a `IDbCommandInterceptor` for implementing an interceptor, but in EF Core 2, I don't know how to write one ?

Comment: there is an open issue in ef core github page . but does not provide any solution.
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1629

Comment: You could try utilizing [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) introduced in EF Core 2.1, for instance associating value converter like this `new ValueConverter<string, string>(v => v == "" ? null : v, v => v)` with all these properties (columns).

Comment: I have the exact opposite of this ... I'm giving it an empty string and it's complaining with a Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException that the field cannot be null.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new [`IDbCommandInterceptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.idbcommandinterceptor?view=efcore-3.1) interface that should be able to handle this, but it looks complicated.

A simple approach is be to write a function to remove empty strings, and then call it before data is saved within your `DbContext` class.

```
public void RemoveEmptyStrings()
{
    // Look for changes
    this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    // Loop through each entity
    foreach (var entity in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        // Use reflection to find editable string properties
        var properties = from p in entity.Entity.GetType().GetProperties()
            where p.PropertyType == typeof(string)
                  && p.CanRead
                  && p.CanWrite
            select p;

        // Loop through each property and replace empty strings with null
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(property.GetValue(entity.Entity, null) as string))
                property.SetValue(entity.Entity, null, null);
       }
    }
}
```

Remember to override each version of `SaveChanges()`, `SaveChanges(bool)`, `SaveChangesAsync()` in your `DbContext` class.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    // Replace empty strings with null
    this.RemoveEmptyStrings();

    // Continue with base functionality
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: ```SaveChanges()``` seems to call ```SaveChanges(bool)``` and ```SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken)``` seems to call ```SaveChangesAsync(bool, CancellationToken)``` under the hood so overriding the versions with only the bool seems to be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with storing a different value in your DB than is in your domain object.  Any code that touches this object will behave differently after it's hydrated from the DB.

If you always use String.IsNullOrEmpty(val), you will be ok, but there's guarantee that all code tests strings this way.